# Get object that was destructured in parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a function that takes a destructured object as a parameter in an arrow function:

```
const myFunc = ({a, b, c}) => {
};
```

Is there anyway or syntax that would allow me to get that whole object as a single value as well? Since the arrow function doesn't bind `arguments`, I can't use that.

Is it possible to name it, something along the lines of:

```
const myFunc = (allArgs: {a, b, c}) => {
    console.log(allArgs);
};
myFunc({a:1, b:2, c:3}); // Output: {a:0, b:1, c: 2}
```

Obviously, this isn't a deal breaker and there are plenty of workarounds (either don't use an arrow function, don't destructure, or recreate the object when I need it), but I'd like to know for convenience sake.

Answer (score 11):

You could destructure a single param quite easily. You lose the advantage of the terse destructuring syntax in the arguments, but it's easy and still clear:

```
const myFunc = (allArgs) => {
    const {a, b, c} = allArgs;
    console.log(allArgs);
};
```

Alternatively, consider whether you need an arrow function. If you don't need access to the lexical `this` perhaps a good old-fashioned `function() {}` will do the trick and give you access to `arguments`.

Comment: Thanks, those are both good possibilities. I'd definitely considering using a normal `function` syntax, but hadn't though of just destructing immediately in the method. That's a relatively clean approach.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer an expression, which means you typically also need an extra `return` at the end.

Comment: It actually solves the question, why isn't it accepted?